# creating buttons with foreach loop and pass argument to a procedure with button click in tcl

Tags: button, tcl, procedure

I am trying to create some buttons in tcl. Based on the button clicked I would like to pass different arguments to a procedure.

```
set cord_y 25
foreach {x but_name arg1 arg2} {1 button-1 val1 val2 2 button-2 val3 val4 3 button-3 val4 val5 4 button-4 val6 val7 5 button-5 val8 val9} {
    button $a.$x -text $but_name -command {print $arg1 $arg2}
    place $a.$x -x 20 -y $cord_y -width 80 -height 25
    
    set cord_y [expr $cord_y+35]
    }

proc print {i j} {
    puts "$i--$j"
    }
```

the output is always val8--val9 irrespective of the buttons clicked.
How do i pass different argument from each button calls.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line

```
button $a.$x -text $but_name -command {print $arg1 $arg2}
```

Because the `print` command is enclosed in `{}` the values of `arg1` and `arg2` only get substituted when the command is *run*.  What you want is for them to be substituted when the command is *defined*.  To achieve this you should do

```
button $a.$x -text $but_name -command [list print $arg1 $arg2]
```

(Actually in this case you could just use `-command "print $arg1 $arg2"` but that would fail if arg1 or arg2 contained spaces or other special characters.)